# Laravel4: Checking many-to-many relationship attribute even when it does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

This is my first time with Laravel and also Stackoverflow...

I am developing a simple course management system. The main objects are `User` and `Course`, with a many-to-many relationship between them. The pivot table has an additional attribute, `participant_role`, which defines whether the user is a *student* or an *instructor* within that particular course.

```
class Course extends Eloquent {
  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('participant_role')->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

However, there is an additional role, *system admin*, which can be defined on the `User` object. And this brings me mucho headache. In my blade view I have the following:

```
@if ($course->pivot->participant_role == 'instructor') {
  // do something here...
}
```

This works fine when the user has been assigned to that particular `$course` and there is an entry for this user-course combination in the pivot table.

However, the problem is the system administrator, who also should be able to access course details. The if-clause above gives **Trying to get property of non-object** error, apparently because there is no entry in the pivot table for system administrator (as the role is defined within the `User` object).

I could probably solve the problem by using some off-the-shelf bundle for handling role-based permissions. Or I could (but don't want to) do something like this with two internal if-clauses:

```
if (!empty($course->pivot)) {
  if ($course->pivot->participant_role == 'instructor') {  
    // do something...
  }
}
```

Other options (suggested in partially similar entries in Stackoverflow) would include 1) reading all the pivot table entries to an array, and use in_array to check if a role exists, or even 2) SQL left join to do this on database level.

However, ultimately I am looking for a compact one-line solution? Can I do anything similar to this, which unfortunately does not seem to work?

```
if (! empty ($course->pivot->participant_role == 'instructor') ) {
  // do something...
}
```

The shorter the answer, the better :-). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think there's a perfect way of doing it. You could try one of these:

**One if, `&&` operator**

```
if (!(empty($course->pivot) && $course->pivot->participant_role == 'instructor') {
    // ...
}
```

Although this is pretty much the two ifs you didn't want to do in a single one, it's a one-liner and works because of short-circuit evaluation, where the second condition won't be checked if the first one isn't already true.

**Error Control Operator** (Not recommended)

```
if (@$course->pivot->participant_role == 'instructor') {
    // ...
}
```

This is probably the shortest and better looking solution, but not really recommended. Usage of the `@` operator suppresses any errors, including critical ones, slows down your code and may bring unexpected trouble when debugging the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards creating an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) that checked both the pivot table value, and whether or not the user has system admin access. Then use that accessor to do your permission check, instead of the whole thing in your view.

I'm not really sure how you're laying out your info and view, and it's probably not the best idea to inject User logic into your Course model, so where and how exactly you'd lay out the accessor is not something I can confidently suggest definitively. But it may get you on the right track.